# How to disable options requests in express?

Tags: node.js, security, express

I got this after scanning my website with some online tool:

OPTIONS method is enabled
LowOpen
Vulnerability description
HTTP OPTIONS method is enabled on this web server. The OPTIONS method provides a list of the methods that are supported by the web server, it represents a request for information about the communication options available on the request/response chain identified by the Request-URI.

Should I and how can I disable accepting options requests in express please?

Comment: If you are using anything CORS-related that would require a preflight request, then probably rather not ...

Comment: Besides, I don't see that big of harm in this to begin with (and the tool you are using probably neither, since the message contains "Low" in presumably a keyword position) - your server could either tell me via an OPTIONS request that it supports method XY, or I just make a method XY request directly, and see what happens ...

Comment: thanks, feeling educated